# How to Copy Local Storage Image to Clipboard WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, clipboard

I have an application, where user download images to the Local App Storage, it works like this because in order for the application to display content properly we dont want the user to have direct contact with the images and alter them.

Now we want the user to be able to copy the image to the clipboard or to make a copy in Pictures Library. The problem is that I'm getting this exception when trying to do it.

The code example is here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds7sm.jpg

If I copy the image selecting it with the file picker, or getting it from Pictures Library my code works fine. But this happens when doing it from the Local Storage Folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has mistake. Remove "\\" from this line

`StorageFile storageFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("Circulo 2_Atomo.png")`